# Determining Time Complexity of Algorithm (DFS? Sorta?)

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, depth-first-search

I was recently given the following problem:
You are an auctioneer, and you need to print signs numbered from 1 to upperBound.  You are worried some of the signs may get flipped and become unrecognizable, so you decide to underline every number that may be confusing.
Write code that will generate all of the confusing numbers.

Constraints:

- Confusing numbers: 0, 1, 6, 8, 9
- No number will have a leading zero

I first came up with a brute force, linear solution, and then decided to optimize it.
First I utilized a set to cut my work in half, but that still kept it as a linear problem.
By thinking of it as a tree, with each digit a branch, I was able to implement a sorta backtracking solution (lines 25/26 and 35/36), which allows me to skip huge gaps in the range.

I have no idea how to describe the time complexity, though.  In order to measure it, I counted how many times the flipNumbers while loop runs, as that seemed a good stand-in for the code as a whole.
It developed this fractal pattern that I'm not sure how to describe.

```py
class Solution:
    def __init__(self, upperBound: int) -> None:
        self.confusing = {
            0: 0,
            1: 1,
            6: 9,
            8: 8,
            9: 6,
        }
        self.loops = 0
        self.upperBound = upperBound
        self.answer = self.generateConfusingNumbers()
    def generateConfusingNumbers(self) -> set:
        answer = set()
        if self.upperBound >= 9:
            answer.update([6, 9])
        i = 15
        while i <= self.upperBound:
            i += 1
            if not i % 10 or i in answer:
                continue
            flipped = self.flipNumber(i)
            if flipped[0] and i != flipped[0] and flipped[0] <= self.upperBound:
                answer.update([i, flipped[0]])
            elif not flipped[0]:
                i += (10 ** (flipped[1] - 1)) - 1
        return answer
    def flipNumber(self, number: int) -> tuple:
        answer = 0
        digCount = 0
        while number > 0:
            self.loops += 1
            number, digit = divmod(number, 10)
            digCount += 1
            if digit not in self.confusing:
                return (None, digCount)
            digit = self.confusing[digit]
            answer = answer * 10 + digit
        return (answer, digCount)
    def printAnswer(self):
        print(len(self.answer))
        print(self.answer)
    def printWork(self):
        print(self.upperBound, self.loops)
```

Graphs to show work:
[Shows work for runs 100 - 10000](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJ08J.png)

[Shows runs for 6000-7000](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPni2.png)

[Comparison between optimized code and original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtkzc.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have a loop that counts to upperBound, so the complexity of your algorithm is at least O(upperBound).  You call `flipNumber` for some fixed proportion of those, so the total complexity is multiplied by however long `flipNumber` takes.

That actually takes O(log upperBound) on average, so your total complexity is O(uppperBound log upperBound).

That is a lot longer than it *should* take.

Any task to "generate all..." takes time at least proportional to the size of the output, and you can get that bound just by counting in base 5, and then mapping the digits [0,1,2,3,4] => [0,1,6,8,9].

The size of the output is about upperBound<sup>log 5/log 10</sup>, which makes the appropriate complexity O(upperBound<sup>0.7</sup>)

Note that this doesn't include the time required to actually print all the numbers.

Comment: "You have a loop that counts to upperBound, so the complexity of your algorithm is at least O(upperBound)."

Is that still true since it doesn't count directly to upperBound (the line "i += (10 ** (flipped[1] - 1)) - 1")?